# How to access GitHub Organization shared workflows on private repos?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-organizations

I followed the guide here https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/sharing-workflows-with-your-organization.

I successfully created a GitHub Organization shared workflow and can access this shared workflow if I create a **public** repo under the organization or my account (I am a member of the organization).

However, if I create a private repo I do not see the shared workflow. I am using the free-tier for my membership account and organization, so I'm not sure if that is the issue. There was no documentation stating that was a requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only possible in GitHub Enterprise plan organizations:

> to use templates to create workflows in private repositories, the organization must be part of an **enterprise plan**.
> [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/sharing-workflows-with-your-organization#creating-a-workflow-template)

Answer (score 0):

> You can also create workflow templates in the `.github` repository and
> share them with other users in your organization.

Comment: It seems like you quote this from somewhere. Instead of posting an image of the source, it would be more helpful to post a ***link*** to the source, with proper attribution

Comment: Yeah I keep seeing this mentioned but I've tried and can't seem to get it to work. Can't find any official documentation on it either.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/sharing-workflows-with-your-organization

> You can also create workflow templates in the .github repository and
> share them with other users in your organization.